# Get contentEditable data and post it via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable, var

I have the following div:

```
<div id="txt_reporter" contenteditable="true">I am contents</div>
```

and the following jquery:

```
<script>
$('#submit_inc').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();  

    $('#dynamic_content').html('Submitting...');

 var txt_reporter = $('#txt_reporter').attr("contenteditable", "true");


    $.ajax({
        url: 'tools/inc_submit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'ckc='+ txt_reporter,
        dataType: 'html'
    })      


 .done(function(data){ console.log(data);       
     $('#dynamic_content').html('');
     $('#dynamic_content').html(data);   
    })          
});
</script>
```

The result i'm getting is:

```
  Array ( [ckc] => undefined )
```

How do I get the contents of the editable div:

```
   <div id="txt_reporter" contenteditable="true">
```

into a var and the post it via ajax

Comment: try `var txt_reporter = $('#txt_reporter').attr("contenteditable")` This will return true. The way you use it is normally to set an attr, not to read it's value

Comment: Also getting the data from a div is `var content = $('#dynamic_content').html();` So without the ''

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 var txt_reporter = $('#txt_reporter').attr("contenteditable", "true");
```

To

```
 var txt_reporter = $('#txt_reporter').html();
```

Right now, the first statement is setting the attribute `contenteditable` To `true`. You only wish to retrieve the HMTL of the `txt_reporter` div.